# WCF Service returning XML

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have what I believe to be a fairly simple question but have not been able to find any answers online.  I have a WCF service that takes in three parameters and will return a list of numbers (ids).  For now the three incoming parameters are completely ignored and I am just testing the return values.  This is where I run into my problem.  I need to return, in XML, a list of candidate ids.  The specifications require that the list look as follows:

```
<Disabled>
       <Candidate>123456789</Candidate>
       <Candidate>ABCDEFGHI</Candidate>
</Disabled>
```

How can I get the WCF service to return the data like this.  When using a list the data is returned as follows:

```
<Disabled>
     <Candidate>
            <a:string>test</a:string>
            <a:string>test1</a:string>
     </Candidate>
<Disabled>
```

Is there any way to change this to return as shown above without asking our clients to changes the specifications on their side?

Here are my datacontracts for both the request and response:

```
 [DataContract]
    public class RequestDeactivated
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 0)]
        public string companyId { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public string companyToken { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public int verificationToken { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ResponseDeactivated
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<string> Candidate { get; set; }

    }
```

I have never created a service that returns a list like this so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Edit: I have include the code behind that handles what is actually returned.  Please note I am just testing at the moment and have not added the logic in here.

```
public ResponseDeactivated Deactivate(RequestDeactivated data)
{
    ResponseDeactivated d = new ResponseDeactivated();
    d.Candidate = new List<string>();
    d.Candidate.Add("test");
    d.Candidate.Add("test1"); 
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Return `ResponseDeactivated` No need to deal with xml. Those frameworks are here to do these works (xml/json serializetion/deserializetion etc) for you.

Comment: When I just return ResponseDeactivated I get the formatted with the a:string which I do not want.  I will update my question so that my code handling what is returned right now is displayed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Setup your root node as a collection of strings, whith each item in the colleciton having an item name of "Candidate".

```
[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "Candidate")]
public class ResponseDeactivated : Collection<string>
{

}
```

Then you can serialize like this:

```
ResponseDeactivated o = new ResponseDeactivated();
o.Add("123456789");
o.Add("ABCDEFGHI");

DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ResponseDeactivated));            

serializer.WriteObject(stream, o);
```

Comment: Looking into this now.  Thank you very much for your reply.  I will let you know if it works and mark it as an answer.

Comment: EDIT:  Your solution worked!  Thank you so much.  After doing a bit of research I discovered that I did not even need to serialize the ResponseDeativated.  It seems that everything is handled for me.  I simple changed the DataContract to a CollectionDataContract and removed the datamember I had.  If anyone else has questions Ill be happy to upload my working code for them. Thanks again